# How to get flag arguments in other package

Tags: go

I write program in go, and I have a problem with get variable form command line in other own package using package **flag** .

> flag.Parse()

Main problem is in **Configuration package**, because I use her many times in many places, so I want to avoid pass pionter to her, and I decided create as an independent module. Now I have problem with get flag to pathFile with configuration. My code looks like below

I run my program with parameter

> program -config=/my/path/config.cfg

and main function

```
func main() {
        flag.Parse()
      // some next operation but not with configuration Type
      // the type of configuration is use in other object 
      //and in other place in my program
      //  here I only want to parse plag from
      // cmd lines
}
```

**package configuration** and file configuration.go so **configuration/configuration.go**

```
var (
    configPath string
    C          *configuration
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&configPath,
        "config",
        "/defaultpath/config.gcfg",
        "Path to configuration file")
    C = &configuration{}
    if err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(C, configPath); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot read configuration file. Program was Terminated error:%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

type configuration struct {
    Queue struct {
        User                    string
        Host                    string
        Port                    string
}
```

> After compilation I get error: Cannot open log file error:open
>   /defaultpath/config.gcfg: no such file or directory. Program was
>   terminated.

As look above Parsed flags in main are not visible in package configuration, because configuration module try start with default path nor form arguments cmd line. that's why this must be finish error, because this path dosen't exist in my local machine

Question on end is:
How export flag variable from main package to other own package ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init()` in `configuration` is run before *anything* in `main` is executed, so there's no way the effect of `flag.Parse()` could be seen. You also need to declare the flag variables before you call `flag.Parse()`

You can't export anything from `main`, both because `main` can't be imported, and because you can't have a circular dependency between the packages. Have the `main` package call a function from the configuration package to get the behavior you want.

You could add an exported `Init()` function in `configuration` to handle the flag options:

```
func Init() {
    flag.StringVar(&configPath,
        "config",
        "/defaultpath/config.gcfg",
        "Path to configuration file")
    flag.Parse()

    C = &configuration{}
    if err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(C, configPath); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot read configuration file. Program was Terminated error:%s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

and have the `main` function start with

```
func main() {
        configuration.Init()
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I done exacly what You wrote, and I get error `flag provided but not defined: -config
Usage of /tmp/Unnamed1go:` I think that I will be must define this path as constans...

Comment: @Mbded: You're probably calling `flag.Parse` before you define the flag. Are you still calling it from `main`?

Comment: No. I calling`flag.Parse()` form particular package after define flag exacly as You wrote above and I still get error `flag provided but not defined` This looks like function `Parse` works only in main.go file and every operation must be in main. So only way to solve this is pass parsed flags to particular function as argument,  so for me will be solution eg after flag.Parse() `configuration.Init(pathToConfiguration)`

Comment: @Mbded: I assure you that this works, and creating some minimal packages that do only this produces no errors, and outputs the default or the flag argument correctly.

Comment: May be I see one diffrent. My file `main.go` is located in `project/cmd/service/main.go` and configuration.go is located in `project/config/configuration.go` so may be here is a problem ? I thought that is dosen't important